# Neaten Python one-liner on reading a multidimensional array

Tags: python, file-io, multidimensional-array

I have this one-liner:

```
board = [[int(cell) for cell in row] for row in [line.split() for line in boardFile]]
```

Which reads a text file like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And creates a multidimensional array like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, it looks rather not neat, can anyone improve it?

Comment: You could not have a one liner and split it up...

Comment: Your list comprehension is perfectly fine...

Comment: Requests for improvement of existing code get better answers from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

```
board = [map(int, line.split()) for line in boardFile]
```

or `board = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in boardFile]` in Python 3.

Comment: Later on in my code, it returns the error: `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`

Comment: @Lewis: in that case either you are using Python 3, or you have reassigned the name `map` to mean something other than the `map` builtin (which is a really bad idea, but Python doesn't stop you).

Answer (score 2):

The simple method is

```
[[int(cell) for cell in line.split()] for line in boardFile]
```

Comment: +1 On consideration, this is probably better than my answer. `map` is only marginally useful to begin with compared to comprehensions, and without the questioner specifying Python 2 or Python 3 it proved not to be worth my while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how you define a line with multiple adjacent spaces, this might be easier:

```
import sys
r=csv.reader(boardFile, delimiter=' ')
board=list(r)
```